# Visual Studio Understands but Unity Doesn't?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, using

I've installed the Microsoft.Identity.Client in Visual Studio and can now declare `using Microsoft.Identity.Client;` within the code. Visual Studio is happy. Unity, however, is not.

```
Assets\Scripts\AutoKhan.cs(8,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

What must I do to make Unity similarly happy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into similar issues when using external libraries. Often there is a dll to add to your project because of how Unity compiles your project.

This may be useful. 
[How to use an external dll](https://answers.unity.com/questions/458300/how-to-use-a-external-dll.html#:~:text=To%20use%20an%20external%20DLL,your%20Visual%20Studio%2FMonoDevelop%20project.)

Comment: Perfect. I found a Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService and I added it to Assets/Plugins. Worked like a charm!

Comment: That was DEFINITELY not the right dll to copy! Haha. Instead, I had to follow the function which showed where it was located at the top of the file so I could copy THAT dll. It was at W:\<my_project>\Packages\Microsoft.Identity.Client.4.14.0\lib\net45 which I still had to copy to Assets/Plugins to get Unity to see it.