# When Calling from within a Unity App, What to Put for Parent Object in MSAL's AcquireTokenInteractive?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to authenticate with MSAL library. What is the purpose of "object parent" in the function call? Best I found was it's supposed to be the parent Window. I've tried putting `this` (dumb, I know) and I've tried `FindWindow(null, "AppName")` (from user32.dll) to get an IntPtr to the window of the app, but everything yields a null error when calling the function. So what should go there to enable this function to work? Does Unity have a specific handle to whatever this should be?

And why in the world do the docs not at all mention this required parent??
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.ipublicclientapplication.acquiretokeninteractive?view=azure-dotnet

Edit: I was mostly concerned with what the "object parent" is supposed to be. Without knowing what it's supposed to be, I don't know how to call the function. As seen in the image below, Visual Studio is flagging the call without it and forcing me to put it in. I am now including the rest of the code in case someone wishes to point out something else entirely that I may be doing wrong apart from the question regarding the use of "parent".

```cs
    using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

    public async void SharepointLogin()
    {
        IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindow(null, "MyAppName"); // This is the "parent" object that I have no idea what it's supposed to be as it is not documented.
        IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;
        Debug.Log("Creating PublicClientApplicationBuilder");
        PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                .Build();
        Debug.Log("Getting Accounts");
        var accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        IEnumerable<string> scopes = new List<string> { "User.Read" };
        AuthenticationResult result;
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("Trying Silent Token");
            result = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed. Trying Interactive Token");
            // This is the line where I can't remove the "parent" object 
            // (in this case "windowPtr") without the error seen in the image 
            // below. It has no compile problems like this but it always has a 
            // null pointer exception when it runs. Everything is the same in the 
            // first "Try" except this "parent" object I'm forced to supply.
            result = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes, windowPtr)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Since I am unable to mock run your code.  I am left to ask obvious questions, are you sure, that `scopes` is a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>` ?  Based on the error, this error, is entirely due to a syntax problem.  **The reason it's not documented is because it actually isn't required.** [Research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796024/authenticating-against-azure-magment-api-sdk-with-msal-net)

Comment: As you can see in the image, Visual Studio is absolutely requiring that I put "something" in the parent spot. As for the scopes, yes, it is very much that. So I can only assume it must have something to do with the one item that I have no idea what it's supposed to be used for.

Comment: `AcquireTokenInteractive` absolutely does not require it.  The error message is just not clear.  Since you have failed to provided the minium amount of code to diagnose your problem, I am once again going to ask a stupid question, is `PublicClientApp` defined as a `IPublicClientApplication`?  Likewise, is `result` defined as a `AuthenticationResult `?  Additionally, what is the value of `scopes`?

Comment: See Update. Since Visual Studio is indeed forcing the use of "parent" then perhaps that is somehow my issue. No clue how that could be since I didn't write the dll though...? The error goes away if I put something there and is fine with my IEnumerable.

Comment: @CodeMonkey can you verify you are using Microsoft.Identiy.Client v4.14.0 as you linked there is no param for parent mentioned and I can see that it wants a generic object in your screenshot which isn't overly helpful as you mentioned also. I would recommend checking you are on the right documentation for the version you are using. Another thing to try is to right click the method and see the source. A lot of times there will be an explanation above the method declaration.

Comment: Can't see the source and there are no comments. How can I see which version I'm using?

Comment: I managed to find the version that Visual Studio is comparing against and it is indeed v4.14.0. So that is super weird that it doesn't match the documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Skyler Lauren was on the right track. Though Visual Studio claimed I had 4.14.0 installed, whatever version of the dll I had copied (3.0) from when he answered [Visual Studio Understands but Unity Doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223096/visual-studio-understands-but-unity-doesnt) ended up trumping the version VS was using. Deleting the one I copied into the Unity folder, uninstalling, reinstalling, and following the function to determine where the REAL dll existed resulted in me no longer needing a "parent" object. Doesn't answer the question what the "parent" was in the first place, but that's now a moot point since I was using the wrong dll. It also doesn't solve my problem with null exception, but that will now be a different question.